# Cannot iterate through array of bytes with specifically assigned index locations

Tags: java

I have an array of bytes. The array has n number of messages. The first 12 indices of the array are a sequence number and a UTC time stamp. It is always guaranteed that the next 2 bytes are the size of the first message in bytes. All messages following the first message follow the format of first 2 bytes are the next message size and then the rest of the bytes are for that particular message.

I am attempting to break down the bigger array into smaller arrays of individual messages.

I wrote a while loop that starts at the index of the first 2 bytes for the first message size (always at index 12). I convert the bytes to Hexadecimal then finally to Decimal and I use those values as my starting and ending points.

The while loop then sets the start value to the end value + 1 to grab the next 2 bytes of the next possible message size and the process starts all over for the next message.

Here is the problem. Upon a second iteration through the while loop when I attempt to set my variable "result" to the hexadecimal values at the index specified by the variables "start" and "start2" the values being returned all the time is 0. I can look at the original message and see that there are more messages after the first but it seems like I am not able to set the index on my original array more than once inside the while loop. using System.out.print I can see that the correct index values are being set for variables "start" and "start2" just before they are used on the original array i where I am converting from byte to hexadecimal then saving to the String variable "result". But the result is populating with 0. The first iteration through the while loop works fine.

here is my code:

```
private static void parseArray(byte[] i) {
    byte[] newArr = null, headerArr;
    String result;
    int start = 12, start2 = 0, begin = 0, end = 0;

    headerArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(i, 0, 11);

    while(start < i.length)
    {
        //assign index of 2nd byte in MsgSize to increment value in array
        start2 = start + 1; 

        //assign starting index for original array of the nth message
        begin = start; 

        //assigns byte 2 of MsgSize first
        result = Integer.toHexString(i[start2] & 0xFF); 
        //assigns byte 1 of MsgSize second
        result = result + Integer.toHexString(i[start] & 0xFF); 

        //result is converted from HEX to DEC for ending index of new array of nth message
        end = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(result, 16);

        //new array is created from begininng to end of parsed nth message
        if(end != 0)
        {
            newArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(i, begin, end);
            sendnewArray(headerArr, newArr);
        }

        // end of original array, no more to parse
        if(end == 0)
        {
            break; 
        } 
        // original array, more messages to parse set index of start to
        // index of end + 1
        else if (end != 0)
        {   
            start = end + 1;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Durandal pointed out, [Arrays.copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-byte:A-int-int-) requires a start index and end index, but you are passing the message's byte count as the final argument.  This means that if the third message happened to start at index 2000 and end at index 2050, you would be calling `Arrays.copyOfRange(i, 2000, 50)`, which should throw an exception.

It is not a good idea to use Strings to perform numeric conversions.  The [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class is well suited to what you are trying to do.  It maintains its own [position](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position--) (index) and you can read a two-byte value using its [getShort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getShort--) method:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(i);
byte[] headerArr = new byte[12];

while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {

    buffer.get(headerArr);

    int length = buffer.getShort() & 0xffff;
    if (length == 0) {
        break;
    }

    byte[] newArr = new byte[length];
    buffer.get(newArr);

    sendnewArray(headerArr, newArr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you to both of you. I have heard of little endian but never looked into it. ByteBuffer seems to be the way to. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You probably confused yourself with your variable names, what you parse into `end` is really  the *length* of a particular message. Therefore you need to use it as an *offset* you add to start before using it for anything. Step it through with a debugger and it should become rather clear.

Note: Conversion of the two bytes into an offset can be done more elegantly and swiftly using *masking, shifting and bitwise or operator*:

```
int length = ((i[start + 1] & 0xFF) << 8) | (i[start] & 0xFF);
```

No weird string intermediates needed.

Edit: I played with your code, you make things really convoluted thats why you probably have trouble finding where your variables stray off. Simplify your code.

The mistakes are treating the parsed length as a direct index into the array (where it should be start + length) and when advancing start to the *next* message you add one. A message starts at index "start" and it *ends* at "start + length" (*exclusive*). The next message begins at "start + length" (*inclusive*).

Doing all this it simplifies to:

```
void parseArray(byte[] array) {
    int start = 12;

    byte[] headerArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, start);

    while(start < array.length) {
        // parse length (2 bytes, little endian)
        int length = ((array[start + 1] & 0xFF) << 8) | (array[start] & 0xFF);

        // if length zero, finished
        if(length == 0)
            break;

        //new array is created from begininng to end of parsed nth message
        byte[] newArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, start, start + length);
        sendnewArray(headerArr, newArr);

        // position start onto next message
        start += length;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I saved the message length to a new variable and added the start variable to that. Then set it to the end variable. I am still getting the 0's in iterations over 1....Argh!!!!

Comment: @user1789170 Are you sure you parse the bytes in the right order? (does a message of two bytes length look like 00 02 or 02 00?)

Comment: strangely enough yes. the message size is usually just the first byte of the 2 but depending on the size of the message both bytes 1 and 2 are used and byte 2 must be put in front to get the correct size....I don't know the reason but only I am following the protocol set by those who are sending the packet of data

Comment: @user1789170 Its called *byte order*, x86 CPU's use little endian (meaning the *least* significant byte occupies the lowest address). As opposed to big endian (aka network byte order) where the *most* sigificant byte is at the lowest address. Many protocols just expose that platform detail in their definition (because nobody thought of it or whatever).